# Uploading file selenium wd + jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, file-upload, selenium

There is page with the element:

```
<div class="block-title-inside">
     <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="block-title-link fright" style="display:block; overflow: hidden; width: 105px;">Upload video <span class="blue-arrow-right"></span>
     <input type="file" name="file" id="videoUpload" class="dpt-mediafile-input-button" style="z-index: 999"></a>
Videos</div>
```

There is no "Attach" button so while clicking "Upload video" button shown above user is seeing native OS window with ability to choose file to upload.

I can't upload file using selenium WD and simple code such as doesn't work:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("videoUpload")).sendKeys("D://Other//sample_videos//barsandtone.FLV");
driver.findElement(By.id("videoUpload")).click();
```

The problem seems to be that the site uses jQuery upload script. Here are the parts of JS code that is related:

1. http://www.speedyshare.com/DEXEQ/main.js (the script itself can't be seen by guest users)
2. Two links, please separate: __http://www.dailypreptalk.com/components/com_dpt/assets/file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js">http://www.dailypreptalk.com/components/com_dpt/assets/file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js_**_**_http://www.dailypreptalk.com/components/com_dpt/assets/file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js

I tried to run js code:

```
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('videoUpload').value = 'D://Other//sample_videos//barsandtone.FLV'");
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('videoUpload').click()");
```

But still no result. I also tried to initialize window using jQuery code but no chances as well:

```
js.executeScript("dpt.jQuery('#videoUpload').value = 'D://Other//sample_videos//barsandtone.FLV'");
js.executeScript("dpt.jQuery('#videosModal').modal('show');");
```

I just can't get how to initialize jQuery upload widget with prefilled file path.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was found using Robot function:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
```

Original code + filepath to D:/1.avi:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("videoUpload")).click();
  driver.getWindowHandle();
  //type path to your file using robot VK language
  try {
      Robot r = new Robot();
      r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D); //D char
      r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT); // colon char
      r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON); // colon char
      r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON); // colon char 
      r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT); // colon char
      r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SLASH); // backslash char etc
      r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
      r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD);
      r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
      r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
      r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_I);
      r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
  } catch (AWTException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```